# Virtual host & DNS on apacheserver

Tags: apache, dns, apache2, system-administration

I was given a DNS-named called xxxx.hosterspace.com to my trial VPS-server located at 111.111.111.111. However, I am having some trouble having that DNS-name as default when I try to enter the server.

Whenever I enter xxxx.hosterspace.com, I end up at 111.111.111.111. I don't know how to fix this, I would like to keep xxxx.hosterspace.com in the addressfield.

This is my apache2.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName xxxx.hosterspace.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/mediawiki/
  <Directory /var/www/mediawiki>
     Allow from all
     Options -MultiViews
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is my sites-enabled/000-default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName xxxx.hosterspace.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/mediawiki/
 <Directory /var/www/mediawiki>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Anyone who knows how to set this up? Don't really get any errors when I try to launch it. I have runned sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Apache configuration file(s) you've posted, I don't see how the redirect could be happening at the Apache level. It looks like you're running MediaWiki, so you may want to look at its configuration file(s) and ensure that MediaWiki isn't causing the redirect to the IP address.